# enlarge / animate map or change viewBox

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

i have this http://bl.ocks.org/nkhine/raw/3150901/ where if you click on a country the code re-renders the map (only USA, UK and Afganistan topo files present)

i am stuck on how to animate the 'country' so that it 'moves' to the center of the screen and also fit the map to the users' viewport?

what i am doing is to fadeout and then remove the 'svg g' element for the id='countries' https://gist.github.com/nkhine/3150901#file-client-js-L120 and then add the id='country' within which i am drawing the country based on the topo file provided.

i tried to remove the entire svg and re-create it, but this does not 'feel' to be the correct approach!

what would be the correct way to alter the viewBox without having to redraw the entire SVG?

any advice much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to change your .on("click") function to translate the image using the centroid of the country that has been clicked on, see the d3 example here http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590.